# Regular Expression (PHP/Perl) Backreferences

Tags: php, regex, perl

I want to match strings of the form:

> Sections 158, 417, 418, 500, 501, and 1111

Where I get all the numbers as backreferences (replacing them with hyperlinks).  I got this far:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/Sections? ([0-9.]+)(?:(?:and|,| |or)+([0-9.]+))+/","hyperlink_me", $text);
```

That's  PHP (which uses perl-compliant regexes).  The PHP part is fine I think, it's the regex that's not doing what I want, but I'm giving the whole line of code for context.

The problem is the only two backreferences I get (other than the whole string)  are for the first number ("158") and the last one ("1111").  It seems like  the second captured backreference ("([0-9.]+") is just getting written over from the second number onwards.  From [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), at "Repetition and Backreferences", I get the idea that this is often an issue, but can't figure out how to solve it in this context.  Any regex geniuses out there who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply how capturing-parentheses work, and can't be avoided. But you can create a "helper" callback, `hyperlink_us`, that does this:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("/[^0-9.]+([0-9.]+)/","hyperlink_me", $input);
```

and then you use it like this:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/(Sections? [0-9.]+(?:(?:and|,| |or)+[0-9.]+)+)/","hyperlink_us", $text);
```

That way, `hyperlink_us` passes all the numbers to `hyperlink_me`, but the caller of `hyperlink_us` can make sure that numbers are only passed in the appropriate contexts (the "Section(s)..." stuff).

(Disclaimer: I'm not much of a PHP-er. I'm assuming that this function behaves like its analogue in JavaScript. I do know Perl, but it doesn't have a callback-based regex-replacement function.)

Comment: Thanks! Mostly I just needed to know that's just how backreferences work, and there wasn't some regex trick I was missing.  I actually ended up using a combination of PHP functions (preg_match_all, str_replace) within my hyperlink_me function to do the same kind of thing as you suggest.

Comment: @joseph_morris: You're welcome! Yeah -- Perl-compatible regexes, like all things Perl, are so full of magical nuances that it's easy to get to thinking they must have a new trick for every occasion, when in fact, they only have a new trick for 99% of occasions. The other 1%, we have to muddle through somehow. :-(